# Java - How to set JTextArea height to fit its content?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea in a JPanel. The JPanel has a null layout or uses absolute layout.
The JTextArea has a fixed width. How can I set the JTextArea height to fit its content?

I have this code:

```
*some random string of varying length*
String str = "kdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkda"
           + "kdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkda"
           + "kdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkda"
           + "kdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkda"
           + "kdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkda"
           + "kdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkdafkakopwepopkkda";


JTextArea wtd = new JTextArea(str);
wtd.setLineWrap(true);
wtd.setOpaque(false);
wtd.setEditable(false);
wtd.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
wtd.setLocation(*defined x position*, *defined y position*);
wtd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(*fixed width*, *the height depending on the content*));
wtd.setSize(wtd.getPreferredSize());
add(wtd);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `null` layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
2. Don't set absolute heights or widths or preferredSize **ever** for JTextAreas -- by doing this you completely prevent their use within JScrollPanes.
3. Instead set the column and row properties of the JTextArea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'm using null layouts because I'm doing some sort of Relative Layout (like in Android). If there's a layout that's similar to a relative layout, what layout is it?

Also, how do I know the number of rows the string I put in it has? The string I put inside the JTextArea can vary and it is not fixed to a certain number of characters.

Comment: @cLix: I'm not familiar with relative layout, but always consider nesting JPanels, each with its own layout to allow for simple creation of complex GUI's. Also look into 3rd party layouts such as MigLayout.

Comment: Nesting JPanels seems a good idea. I'll try to look for a layout that would suit what I would want to do. BTW, the relative layout I'm talking about is a layout wherein the components' position would be based from other components' position. Like for example, if I want a JButton to be under a JLabel, I'm going to get the y position and height of the JLabel and then add them (or add a gap which is defined) and set it to the y position of the JButton. It's something like that.

Comment: @cLix: when asking questions like this, you will want to 1) post an image (or if your rep is too low, a link to an image) showing what you're trying to achieve, and 2) your best [mcve] code attempt.